# Thinktecture IdentityServer3 and Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, azure-ad-b2c

Has anyone used Azure Active Directory B2C as an external identity provider with Thinktecture Identity Server 3?  If you did, how did you set it up?  I can setup relying parties and other external providers such as Google and Facebook with no problem, just not sure where to start with Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 0):

I believe currently Azure b2c cannot be a relying party to someone else. it can only consume others as relying parties to it